# Python Pandas keep the first occurence of a specific value and drop the rest of rows with the same specific value

Tags: python, pandas

I cannot figure out how to get rid of rows (but keep the first occurence and get rid of every row that has the value) with some condition.

I tried using drop_duplicate but this will get rid of everything. I just want to get rid of some rows with a specific value (Within the same column)

Data is formatted like so:

```py
Col_A | Col_B
 5    |   1
 5    |   2
 1    |   3
 5    |   4
 1    |   5
 5    |   6
```

I want it like (based on Col_A):

```py
Col_A | Col_B
 5    |   1
 5    |   2
 1    |   3
 5    |   4
 5    |   6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `idxmax` and check the index.  This of course assumes your index is unique.

```
m = df.Col_A.eq(1)                            # replace 1 with your desired bad value
df.loc[~m | (df.index == m.idxmax())]
```

```
   Col_A  Col_B
0      5      1
1      5      2
2      1      3
3      5      4
5      5      6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df1=df.copy()
mask=df['Col_A'] == 5
df1.loc[mask,'Col_A'] = df1.loc[mask,'Col_A']+range(len(df1.loc[mask,'Col_A']))
df1=df1.drop_duplicates(subset='Col_A',keep='first')
print(df.iloc[df1.index])
```

Output:

```
   Col_A  Col_B
0      5      1
1      5      2
2      1      3
3      5      4
5      5      6
```